# How do constants work in an if block?

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to learn how to make and use "constants". Here is my code:

```
class Constantine(object):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2

    def test(self, code):
        if code not in(self.ONE, self.TWO):
            print("safe")
        else:
            print("not safe")

keeanu = Constantine()
keeanu.test(1)
```

I expect the code to print safe. But, it prints not safe. Why ?

Comment: Is `1` not in `(1, 2)`? The answer to this, is the clue to your confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by "constants"? Python doesn't really have constants. We just all pretend they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing whether `code` is ***not*** in `(self.ONE, self.TWO)`. If it ***is*** found, it will print `not safe`, which it does.

The reason it is found is because the interpreter first looks up `self.ONE` and `self.TWO` as instance variables. If they are not found at that level, the interpreter will attempt to resolve them as class variables. This succeeds for your code.

Comment: Thanks. This code is actually a replacement for the real code i am using. I still get an error in the real code. There are unit tests and all. Gosh, I should have checked the code before posting it.

Comment: TigerhawkT3 - Sorry, but can you please delete your answer so that I can delete this question ? Hope you'll understand my situation. I can upvote some of your other questions to make up for the loss of votes on this question, if you wish.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - As far as I'm aware, you should be able to delete your question regardless of answers. It simply prompts you for confirmation if the question has upvoted answers. That way, if you decide to undelete it in the future, it will still have a corresponding answer.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3-Thanks for your reply. It says that I cannot delete a question with answers, you can flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - If you have a different, unique question to ask, you can ask a new question. This answer will (in theory) help people wondering about this question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3- It will only make me lose points for momentary stupidity. Hope you'll understand. I doubt if majority of the programmers, beginner or expert will find questions like why does if(false) never execute ? Hope you'll understand. Thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - Maybe it could do with a more relevant title, with a mention of class and instance variable resolution?